# showAnnotations when rotation changes

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, orientation-changes

I have a `SplitViewController` with a mapview on as the detailViewController.

I add multiple annotations to the mapview. After adding them I call the [`showAnnotations:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/showAnnotations:animated:) method to zoom in/out the map so that all the annotations are shown in the visible portion of the map.

```
mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

[image]

Now I need the map to refocus itself when the orientation changes because the mapview's visible area reduces when you turn the iPad to portrait. So I call the same `showAnnotations:animated:` method in [`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) method which fires when the orientation changes. But it doesn't work as expected.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

How do I make it refocus when orientation changes?

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83o1greu2oec1t3/DataLoader.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Are you sure the map view is correctly changing its frame (using auto layout or whatever) when orientation changes?  If not, in portrait, the map might be extending beyond the screen which makes the zoom look wrong.

Comment: I don't handle any resizing of the views manually. It's all handled by the OS itself.

Comment: Yes but the OS does what the storyboard/xib says to do: either following the auto layout constraints that are set, or auto-resizing, or size classes, or whatever method is being used.  After rotation happens, log the map view's frame and see if some of it is outside the bounds of the screen.  Don't assume the OS magically knows what you want.

Comment: @Anna I debugged the view hierarchy with Reveal. No, the mapview resizes correctly. No overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `showAnnotations` within the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method works perfectly.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
}
```